# Get rid of GeoTIFFs that fall outside the boundary when adjacent GeoTIFFs overlap each other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, masking, data-driven-pages

I am currently working in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 with data driven pages enabled. I have ten GeoTIFFs with some overlapping into other GeoTIFFs. I want to mask those that are overlapping so when I show a specific grid boundary, it doesn't show the adjacent GeoTIFF on top (refer to pic attached).

[image]

How do I get rid of the overlapping? I know I can extract by mask but that needs to be done individually/ batch processes but that is still some work for a repeat of ten grids. I will eventually need to do 100 so I want to find the most efficient way to complete this task.

Comment: Can't you just turn off the visibility of these "other geotiffs" if you don't want to see them in the layout?

Comment: @Hornbydd: I could but i am currently using DDP and I want to find a way where I don't need to turn on and off the other geotiffs when exporting all maps out. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your image what it is that you want dropped, suggest you include a second image showing the desired output?

Comment: Is there any way to define which layers are shown on top? If so, you could bring whichever layers are in the current page to the top of the layer list. You might also want to look into automating with python - then if there's any otherwise manual steps ("if center of layer not on page, then turn off, etc." you could make the script do that.